# Missing output from pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial

I am reading from the serial port using the following code:

```
z1baudrate = 115200
z1port = '/dev/ttyUSB11'
ser = serial.Serial(z1port, z1baudrate, timeout=0, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,

                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
while True:
    queue = ser.inWaiting()
    if queue > 0:
        data = ser.read(1000)
        print data
    time.sleep(.2)
```

I am supposed to get this result printed every few seconds

```
bbbb::0000:0:0:00 2412 7 -1 250 -58 108 0 2398 # output 1 
bbbb::0000:0:0:00 2475 4 1 264 -46 106 1 2423 # output 2
```

but instead, I occasionally receive incomplete output like

```
bbbb::0000:0:0:00 # sometimes broken into 2 lines
2412 7 -1 250 -58 108 0 2398 # line 2
bbbb::0000 # sometimes a part of the output is missing like this 
bbbb::0000:0:0:00 2475 4 # or like this. Length is variable!
```

What is the problem? Is it a synchronization issue? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a combination of the sleep and print statement. The program might sleep while a sentence is being received, and the when the `print` command is used, it will write a new line, each time.

Try this:

```
import sys

z1baudrate = 115200
z1port = '/dev/ttyUSB11'
ser = serial.Serial(z1port, z1baudrate, timeout=0, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,

                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    sys.stdout.write(data)
```

Comment: I would also try to avoid using the sleep in a loop like this. You should maybe look into the `readline` from pyserial for this.

Comment: How about removing the sleep, will it work? I am currently testing your answer

Comment: And if I use `readline`, then how much should I set the timeout?

Comment: I am testing the `readline` now because the sys.stdout didn't workout. I however got a few times more than one line together like this  as the output `bbbb::0000:0:0:00 2412 7 -1 250 -58 108 0 2398 
bbbb::0000:0:0:00 2475 4 1 264 -46 106 1 2423#  I have two lines together as the output!`This may be due to the fact that I receive the output at random times sometimes, but how to eliminate this?

Comment: Did you remember to `import sys` when using `sys.stdout.write`?

Comment: Let me note that I have already eliminated the problem with the broken output, but the double lines error came out i suppose because I may have not have set the timeout properly, or because I need to include the EOF character in my device that is connected to the serial port. But how do I include it? Is it just a new line at the end?

Comment: I have already implemented the new character and the readline function. They give almost excellent results. Please update this in your answer so I can as the correct answer.